# ActionScript - ComboBox Is SelectableList?

Tags: list, actionscript-3, combobox, flash-v3-components

i don't understand Adobe's documentation for the SelectableList class:

> The SelectableList is the base class
>   for all list-based components--for
>   example, the List, TileList, DataGrid,
>   and **ComboBox** components.

SelectableList isn't a base class for ComboBox:

***SelectableList** > BaseScrollPane > UIComponent > Sprite > DisplayObjectContainer > InteractiveObject > DisplayObject > EventDispatcher > Object*

***ComboBox** > UIComponent > Sprite > DisplayObjectContainer > InteractiveObject > DisplayObject > EventDispatcher > Object*

```
import fl.controls.*;

var l:List = new List();
trace(l is SeletableList); //true

var tl:TileList = new TileList();
trace(tl is SelectableList); //true

var dg:DataGrid = new DataGrid();
trace(dg is SelectableList); //true

var cb:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
trace(cb is SelectableList); //false
```

is this an error?  or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the way Adobe express themselves in the documentation sometimes: confusingly.

To put it in simple OOP terms, it's the difference between extending a class("is a") and using composition("has a"):

List, TileList, DataGrid **is a** Selectable List (because each one extends Selectable List)

ComboBox **has a** Selectable List (because it *has a* List component, exposed through it's [dropdown](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/ComboBox.html#dropdown) property(, which *is a* Selectable list)).

Hope this makes it clear.